# Adding a circle object to pane after button is clicked (JAVA FX)

Tags: java, object, button, javafx, actionevent

I am creating a game where the user can control the human object. However, I would like to add a circle object to the pane to indicate where the human has already travelled. In simpler terms, I would like to leave a trail indicating where the user has travelled.

I would like to know how to add a circle object to the pane every time I press a directional button.

Here is what I have:

```
//Button Action Event for up button
        Up.setOnAction(new EventHandler <ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                //Move object Up
                human.setLayoutY(human.getLayoutY()-80);
                //Keep object within the boundaries
                if(human.getLayoutY()<40) {
                    human.setLayoutY(human.getLayoutY()+80);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: See [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61498537/3992939) of drawing a `Path` object.